# Cannot Import CSV file using Import-Csv

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import a csv file using Import-csv after I converted a excel into a csv file. I'm getting the below error.

> Import-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.

Here is the script I'm using to convert the xls files into csv's and trying to import the csv files at the command prompt

```
$dst="O:\UserCert\target\"
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $False 
$Excel.displayalerts=$False 
foreach ($file in gci "O:\UserCert\*.xls"){
     $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.fullname)
     $wb.SaveAs($dst + $file.Basename + ".csv",6)
     $wb.Close($true)
}
$excel.Quit()
```

Am I making any mistake in the conversion that `Import-csv` was not able to understand?

Comment: What does the complete `Import-Csv` command look like?

Comment: `PS O:\UserCert\Target> Import-Csv "O:\UserCert\Target\HiNetUserCertification_New.csv"`

Comment: What does the csv file look like?  At least a few sample records.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes experience this while using `Import-Csv`.

It turns out to be a conversion problem while saving a .xlsx to .csv.

To fix it, instead of using:

1. File
2. Save As
3. CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)

I do the following:

1. **Start a new Excel instance**
2. **Copy** the contents of my excel spreadsheet
3. **Paste** the contents in the new blank Excel document
4. Save as CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)

The reason this works is because when we do "copy-paste", we effectively copy only the cells with actual content, whereas "save as" exports also empty columns and rows.

By comparing a working CSV and a non-working CSV we can see that in my case there were two additional columns and a few empty rows being created (**potentially empty columns were there used to be content**).

Therefore, another solution is to remove empty columns and rows near the content and then using save as normally. Or also, edit the CSV file and remove the two empty columns for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You normally get that error message if there is problem with the format of the CSV file, have you opened up one in notepad or a text editor and does it look correct? The problem I think maybe due to the way you are creating the CSVs, you are saving the workbook as a CSV but a workbook can't be converted to CSV only a worksheet. Excel normally just saves the active worksheet. Does your Excel file contain more than one worksheet?

Comment: I tried opening through Notepad++ and i can see the data right. yes, there are more than one worksheet in the excel files i'am converting, i see only one sheet in the CSV files after conversion though, when i save those CSV's again manually with csv format then i was able to open with `Import-Csv`

Comment: You are calling the SaveAs method on the workbook, try instead adding an inner foreach looping through each worksheet within each workbook and then the saveAs on the worksheet object.

Comment: foreach ($file in gci "O:\UserCert\*.xls"){`
    $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.fullname)`
    foreach ($ws in $wb.worksheets.item(1)){`
    $ws
    $ws.SaveAs($dst + $file.Basename + ".csv",6)
    }
    $wb.Close($true)
    }

    $excel.Quit()

Comment: Well that blows my hope that I could use Import-CSV to import slightly mis-formed files that Excel chokes on!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually supplying a header to Import-CSV?

I struggled with this same issue, however excel was not a part of my equation, and my files do not have headers to work with. I receive the same error unless I manually specify the -Header property of Import-CSV

Also when I don't know what the headers are I use a range to create a dynamic one. The only thing you need to know is a how many fields there are. The gotcha is that if the ranger is higher than the number of fields they will show up as blank columns.

I tend to use Out-GridView and some guestimates to validate that it works as intended. 
So if I knew there were 30 or less fields I could do the following:

```
Import-CSV "filehere.csv" -Header (1..30) | Out-GridView
```

There are some gotchas to using a range higher than your actual field count, but it's a useful diagnostic trick.

If you find that your file defined header is doing something nefarious under the hood you can Skip the first row and then assign your custom header text or range.